# php publishing issue (Aruba)

Tags: php, jquery, publishing

im publishing my web site on Aruba server.

I have this (simplified):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>My website</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mywebsite/js/jquery.MultiFile.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Testing this on remote and local environment works perfectly.

The problem arises whenever i change the "localhost" src-path (inside the body tag)for a remote one (absolute or relative same issue..the js script doesnt work)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web/htdocs/www.mywebsite.com/home/js/jquery.MultiFile.js"></script>
```

Am I missing something obvious??

p.s. the files  both in local and remote are the same 
thanks
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `/web/htdocs/www.ejoin.it/home/js/jquery.MultiFile.js` isn't a well formed URL (i.e.: it doesn't begin with `http://`, `https://`, `file://`, etc.) and hence it's being ignored by the browser.

Remember - it's the browser that loads the JavaScript includes - this doesn't happen on the server-side, hence you can't meaningfully use a server-side directory path.

Comment: I was definetely missing something obvious =)